# Retrieve N last rows from a mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following command to dump 100 rows from each column from each database. The problem is that it returns the *first* 100 records where I would much rather have the *last*. I found a flag that lets me order by primary key (--order-by-primary), but that still returns the wrong rows. I would try to sneak an 'order by' into the where flag below, but the primary key is different for each table.

```sh
mysqldump -u username -p --where="true limit 100" --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Is there a way to reverse the order before grabbing the last 100 records or perhaps a way of referring to the PK rather than the PK's column name?

Comment: Not really. But you can order on the fields: order by `1,2,3,4,5`. If your PK always consists of the first (x) fields, this works. If your PK is `1,3,5`, it won't :)

Comment: Still interested? I have a linux-version with that revert&limit, it was that easy. It would be useful if the primary key is not the first column for all tables. I try to make a real patch with commandline-options for those things, but not yet sure how to publish it since it needs some mysql-client-libs.

Comment: I try to publish it as MySQL Feature Request 69163, we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as you don't want to patch the mysqldump source code there is just a  workaround.

Try creating a secondary database schema (scheme_dump) and make a script which loops over all tables, fires

```
create table scheme_dump.<tabname> like <tabname>; 
insert into scheme_dump.<tabname> select * from <tabname> order by <colname> desc limit 100;
```

and then dump scheme_dump scheme.

Not nice.

But fixing the source code for a one-shot should not be that hard.

Answer (score -1):

May be this : SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY  DESC LIMIT 100

Comment: that's a flat out syntax error. `desc` is a reserved word, and you can't have a blank order by clause anyways.